# why this keyword is used in java interface and what does it refer?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, this, keyword

I just figured that I can use the `this` keyword in an `interface`.

So, if `this` keyword represents current `class` object reference in a `class`, then what does it represent in an `interface`?

```
interface InterfaceOne {

    default void display() {
        this.defaultMethod();
        System.out.println("InterfaceOne method displayed");
    }

    default void defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("defaultMethod of InterfaceOne called");
    }

}
```

Comment: the current `Object` instance in the scope it´s currently refering to.

Comment: Using `this` at this place is as obsolete as it would be in an ordinary `class`. Maybe it helps to think about what would happen, if you just write `defaultMethod()`, without the obsolete `this`. Then consider that nothing changes when prepending `this.`

Answer (score 6):

Even in this case, the `this` keyword is used in the same context and meaning.

One thing you are missing is, that the `this` keyword represents the current *"Object"* and not current *"Class"*. So, if and when you create an object of this *"Interface"* (by implementing it in another class of course), the `this` keyword will represent that specific object.

For example, if you have,

```
class ClassOne implements InterfaceOne{
}
```

Then, you can have,

```
InterfaceOne one = new ClassOne();

one.display(); // Here, the "this" keyword in your display method, will refer to the object pointed by "one".
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: just going to add that the only exception for `this` is to call an overloaded constructor within another constructor.

Comment: True. But in this question, the context was that of using `this` as a self-reference pointer. That's why I said same context and meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"this" represents the new Instance which implements the interface

```
public interface InterfaceTest {
    default void display() {
        this.defaultMethod();
        System.out.println("InterfaceOne method displayed");
    }

    default void defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("defaultMethod of InterfaceOne called");
    }
}

public class TestImp implements InterfaceTest {

    @Override
    public void defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("xxxx");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestImp imp=new TestImp();
        imp.display();
    }
}

//console print out:
xxxx
InterfaceOne method displayed
```