# It's Possible Interface internally inherit the Object Class

Tags: java, object, inheritance, interface

Interface Implicitly inherit the Object class. Because interface `SubInterface` `default` Method call the `Object`class `hashCode` Method. It's possible then How & Why..?

```
package com.oca.test.exam;

    interface SuperInterface {
        default void printStuff() { System.out.println("Default Method"); }
    }

    interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {
        default void doStuff() {
            this.printStuff();
            System.out.println(this.hashCode());
        }
    }

    public class InterfaceAbstractCombination implements SubInterface{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SubInterface sub = new InterfaceAbstractCombination();
            sub.doStuff();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this` is referring to the instance of `InterfaceAbstractCombination` class, not the interface itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why this keyword is used in java interface and what does it refer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780642/why-this-keyword-is-used-in-java-interface-and-what-does-it-refer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do interfaces inherit from Object class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056124/do-interfaces-inherit-from-object-class-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The interface is not inheriting the `Object` clas. The class which implements the interface `SubInterface` is inheriting the `Object` class.

Just think about it, will you be able to call `doStuff`() of `SubInterface` directly? You need to implement that interface in another class, create an instance of that class then you can call `doStuff()`.

So `InterfaceAbstractCombination` class implements the `SubInterface` and when you call `doStuff()` you calling it on the instance of `InterfaceAbstractCombination` which is supplying the `this.hashCode()` inherited from the `Object` class, so `this` will refer to the instance of the class implementing the interface.

One thing to note, If you check the JLS [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html)

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.

So this is why you are able to call `SuperInterface.super.hashCode();`.

[image]

Comment: One doubt is Still there. in this case  statment SuperInterface.super.hashCode();

Answer (score 0):

The `hashCode` of `InterfaceAbstractCombination` class is provided in your inheritance hierarchy. `this` does not belong to interface, even if it has `default` method.

Consider running below code you'll see same `hashCode` getting printed:

```
package com.oca.test.exam;

  public class InterfaceAbstractCombination implements SubInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubInterface sub = new InterfaceAbstractCombination();
        sub.doStuff();
        System.out.println(sub.hashCode());
    }
    }

    interface SuperInterface {
    default void printStuff() {
        System.out.println("Default Method");
    }
    }

    interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface {
    default void doStuff() {
        this.printStuff();
        System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    }
    }
```